# React: Loop through object and change some property

Tags: javascript

I have this useState:

```
const [fields, setFields] = useState({
  name: {
    value: '',
    error: ''
  },
  lastName: {
    value: '',
    error: ''
  },
  phone: {
    value: '',
    error: ''
  }
});
```

Ok so, at some point, I want to reset all errors, so I can do this:

```
setFields(prev => {
  for (let key in prev) prev[key].error = '';
  return prev;
});
```

But for some reason, this is not working...

Well someone suggested doing this solution and it worked:

```
setFields(prev => {
    const copy = { ...prev };
    for (let key in copy) copy[key].error = '';
    return copy;
  });
```

Comment: What, specifically, does "this is not working" mean?  What did you expect to happen, and what happened instead?

Comment: Consider not modifying state data? Instead create a new object and return that

Comment: Sorry I should've clarified @ScottHunter, what happens is, it updated the state but it doesn't trigger the rerender of the component, idk why

Comment: Consider splitting out the state so it's not all in one object?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
const resetErrors = () => {
let newObject = {...fields};
Object.keys(newObject).map(key => {
  obj[key].error = ''
})
return newObject;
}
.
.
.
setFields(resetErrors());
```